# Error in GetpivotTable formula

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have two pivot tables that I am adding values together within a cell. The problem I have and I haven't figured out how to solve. I am using the GetpivotTable function to do this but if the data isn't there I get a #Ref error. The only way I currently make it work is manually editing it all the time. Which isn't the ideal solution. What's the best way to do this.

**Formula1:** Before Manual Update
`=(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of DEMAND_HOURS",$Z$45,"PROD_MONTH","2014-04","STATUS_ROLLUP","APPROVED","SP_POSITI‌​ON_STATUS","COMMITTED","Project Category","Implementation")+GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of DEMAND_HOURS",$S$85,"PROD_MONTH","2014-04","STATUS_ROLLUP","APPROVED","SP_POSITI‌​ON_STATUS","COMMITTED","Project Category","Implementation"))/152.7`

**Formula2:** After Update
`=(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of DEMAND_HOURS",$Z$45,"PROD_MONTH","2014-04","STATUS_ROLLUP","APPROVED","SP_POSITI‌​ON_STATUS","COMMITTED","Project Category","Implementation"))/152.7`

Comment: Can you show your current formula that you keep on updating manually?

Comment: Here is the formula before the manual update:=(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of DEMAND_HOURS",$Z$45,"PROD_MONTH","2014-04","STATUS_ROLLUP","APPROVED","SP_POSITION_STATUS","COMMITTED","Project Category","Implementation")+GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of DEMAND_HOURS",$S$85,"PROD_MONTH","2014-04","STATUS_ROLLUP","APPROVED","SP_POSITION_STATUS","COMMITTED","Project Category","Implementation"))/152.7

Comment: Here it is after the update:=(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of DEMAND_HOURS",$Z$45,"PROD_MONTH","2014-04","STATUS_ROLLUP","APPROVED","SP_POSITION_STATUS","COMMITTED","Project Category","Implementation"))/152.7

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, sometimes the data in one of the tables is not there. You could use the [`IFERROR`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/iferror-function-HA001231765.aspx) Excel function around each `GetPivotData` function to return a 0 if your pivot table does not contain the data you're looking for.